# How to use aggregation relationship in class diagram?

Tags: java, oop, class-diagram

I have some strange question.

I have a class that composed of 2 classes.

But the main class has not any methods or attributes. only the aggregate classes.

I want to access the 2 other classes using the main class without creating objects directly from them in the main program

Creating objects from the 2 classes is permitted only to the main class and not allowed to the other 2 classes

How to do that?

Comment: So, your title deals with class diagrams (like UML?) but the question talks about actually creating classes without creating objects?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to use nested classes.
You just need to declare the classes as private and you're good to go.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: no private classes, all classes are public. aggregation means having objects from the aggregated classes not having the classes itself.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is then.
You need give a better description on your current state and then clearly state what you are trying to achieve.